# Drupal theme not caching (performance issue)

Tags: php, caching, drupal, drupal-7

I have the following drupal configuration:
Drupal 7.23, using the Domain Access module (https://drupal.org/project/domain), Varnish. I have 4 domains using the same drupal install, but each domain has its own sub-theme (Omega theme 3.x). Everything works fine the problem is that the page load for the last domain is higher then the other ones. I noticed that the theme #4 is not showing up on the 'cache' table. The other ones show up.
It seems that drupal is not caching that particular theme, so it has to load the theme from scratch every time. I have checked the themes .info files they're all the same with the exception of theme name, logo etc...
Any ideas why a theme wouldn't be cached?

Answer (score 0):

We recently had some Drupal cache + Varnish issues.
These were the causes:

1. Check whether cache configuration is correct for the specific domain.
2. If a PHP session is open, the request will not be cached by Varnish. Check if the sub-theme uses $_SESSION variable. If so, that's the problem.
3. Ensure your VCL configuration file is appropriate for Drupal (this issue contains valuable thoughts on it - https://drupal.org/node/1196916)
4. If a custom cookie is used, Varnish may not be able to cache the request. Check if sub-theme sets custom cookie(s).